# Get Last items of Each eloquent pviot

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have this query to get last 20 numbers of each items and it work well but its make about 1400 query so it dosnt standard !

```php
$entire = [];
$items = Item::where('Items.ISDelete' , 0)
    ->join('ItemInfoMain' , 'ItemInfoMain.ItemId' , '=' , "Items.ItemId")
    ->select('ItemInfoMain.ItmId')
    ->get;

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $last20 = ItemInfos::where('ItmId' , $item->ItmId)
        ->orderBy('RowId' , 'desc')
        ->limit(20)
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
    $entire = array_merge($entire , $last20 );
}
```

my ItemifnoMain Model

```
class ItemInfoMain extends Model
{
 protected $table = "ItemInfoMain";
 protected $primaryKey = "ItmId";
 public $timestamps = false;  
 public function itemInfo(){
        return $this->hasMany(ItemInfos::class , 'ItmId');
    }
}
```

my Iteminfos model

```
class ItemInfos extends Model
{

    protected $table = "ItemInfos";
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $primaryKey = "ItmId";
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $incrementing  = true;

    public function itemInfoMain(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ItemInfoMain::class , 'ItmId');
    }
}
```

item model :

```
class Item extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Items";
    protected $primaryKey = "ItemId";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function itemInfoMain(){
        return $this->hasMany(ItemInfoMain::class , 'ItemId');
    }
}
```

i looking forward to find the best optimized sql query 
**my core is sql server**

Comment: Please can you add the code for your `Item` and `ItemInfos` model.

Comment: @rwd i added it

Comment: If this is executing 1400 queries then am I right in assuming that you have about that many `Item`s that you're looping through? What are you doing with `$entire` after you retrieved the data?

Comment: it should return 14000 return and it downloaded by users, how should i do that?